# passing urlencode laravel return 404

Tags: laravel-5

I try to pass url with two parameter but get error 404 which is `bill_number` include `/`

here is my route

```
Route::prefix("monthly-bill")->group(function() {
Route::get("slip/{id}/{bill_number}", "MonthlyBillController@slip");
});
```

when I generate url always return 404

```
url("apt/monthly-bill/slip/".$billing->bill_period_id."/".rawurlencode($billing->bill_number))
```

and this my controller

```
public function slip($bill_period_id, $bill_number)
{
    $convert = new Convert(storage_path("tenant\config\document\slip.blade.php"));

    $convert->data([
        "title" => "Document",
        "date" => date("d F Y"),
        "items" => MonthlyBill::info()
                    ->billPeriod($bill_period_id)
                    ->billNumber($bill_number)
                    ->select("monthly_bill.*",
                        "bpr.*", "t.name", "t.unit_kind", "t.width")->first()
    ]);

    $file = $convert->to("pdf", "invoice-$bill_period_id.pdf", true);

    return response()->file($file);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is here `apt/` in the url ùethod !!

Comment: `apt/` is a folder. make custom module so before access the prefix should include folder name!! what I'am asking is how do I make two parameter with rawurlencode / urlencode

Comment: Check this in your route `Route::prefix("monthly-bill")->group(function() {
 Route::get("slip/{id}/{bill_number}", , function ($id, $bill_number) {
     dd($id ." -- ".$bill_number)
 });
});` if you still get 404 so the problem is in your url function !!

Comment: so thanks for answer :D i'll try @Maraboc

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest generating url with [action()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-action) helper

```
action('MonthlyBillController@slip', [
    'id'          => $billing->bill_period_id,
    'bill_number' => $billing->bill_number,
])
```